# React owl.carousel $ not defined

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have created app using create-react-app. I have imported module jquery in component and also owl.carousel but why it is showing error.

Here is the Component Code

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import $ from '../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min'
import '../../../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel'

import '../../../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css'

class Header extends Component{

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="owl-carousel">
                <div>Content 1</div>
                <div>Content 2</div>
                <div>Content 3</div>
                <div>Content 4</div>
                <div>Content 5</div>
                <div>Content 6</div>
                <div>Content 7</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Cannot read property of undefined.
 [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecrBK.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see from the screenshot that Owl is expecting zepto or jQuery to be on `window`. When you import something it's only available in the scope of that module, not on `window`.

There are several ways to fix this:

Option 1: include jQuery in your `public/index.html` I would recommend using a cdn

Option 2: import jQuery, put in on window, then import owl

```
// note: you don't need the whole path to node_modules.. just the package name
import jQuery from 'jquery'

window.jQuery = jQuery

// dynamically require owl
require('owl.carousel')
```

note: `import` statements need to go before `require` statements

Option 3 (**Best option**):

Just use the [react-owl-carousel](https://github.com/seal789ie/react-owl-carousel) package, or use another carousel package that doesn't need jQuery. Either way importing jQuery into react to use a non-react package is unnecessary these days.